# How to find recursion in your app?

Tags: c#, regex, recursion

My c# service got an internal .net execution error that points to recursion issue (e.g. stack overflow).  The problem is that the service is pretty large, so I am having trouble finding where the recursion actually occurs.

Can someone with massive regex mojo hook me up with a search string that would find what I need?

Comment: No, the only reason I even know that the app crashed is that there is an entry in the Event Log announcing that an internal .net framework error has occurred and gives the code, which i traced to stack overflow issues.

Comment: Did you ever find this problem? If so how? I think most of the people here did not understand that the program crashes with no logging at all except a general stack overflow error in the Service event log.

Answer (score 6):

This is an unanswerable question in the general case. Except for the most trivial examples (e.g. a function calling itself directly), there's no way to analyze a program and determine if recursion occurs. You'll just need to start hitting the debugger or other runtime tools.

This is an example of the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Yes - Very true.  Debugging services is trickier than normal applications, though, which may be why they're asking.

Comment: I think you are overstating it a bit.  In most cases I think some static analysis an find some cycles - this would not be that hard.  Would it be exhaustive?  No, but I think to make a practical check for this would not be so hard.  Using a regex is not going to happen though.

Comment: I think "some cycles" fits with the "most trivial examples" I was trying to get across. But yeah, even then you'd likely need a full parser just to get started.

Answer (score 5):

A recursion is not easy to find in some situations like:

```
method1() {
  method2()
}

method2() {
  method1()
}
```

So a regex probably would not help you to find it unless it's a trivial case.

Comment: Yep.  Build a call graph and look for cycles.

Comment: And hope there are no OS callbacks involved in the recursion ;)

Answer (score 4):

How about using a profiling tool like [RedGate's Ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html)?

They both offer free trials.  Just run the code with the profiler running and it will quickly show you where your time/memory is being spent.

I'd bet that your problem recursive function will stick out quite a bit.

Additionally, what error logging framework are you using?  In case the answer is none, consider adopting one.  [This Question deals with the options.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98080/what-is-the-best-logging-solution-for-a-c-net-3-5-project/98791#98791)  With a good system, you should be able to get the stack trace which, if you're lucky, may give you clues as to where the exception is occurring.

Comment: I have hundreds of installations around US, this is the only instance that is giving me fits. I can't replicate the problem, but I'd like to at least get close to it, by locating the recursion

Answer (score 4):

I agree a regexp isn't going to cut it here.

A more direct way would be to get a dump file and look at it to see where the exception was thrown.

Or you could look at a static analysis tool like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) to examine the programs flow.

Answer (score 2):

Attach to [the service in the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(VS.80).aspx) and debug it properly.  You will find this much easier than trying to search the code of any reasonably sized project.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to get a stack trace of the thing that is crashing. The stack trace will look like this:

```
Blah
Foo
Baz
Hello
...
Frob
Frob
Frob
Frob
[several hundred more Frobs]
Frob
Frob
...
Frob
Something -- crash!
```

The "Frob" is the recursive function. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In dotnet 5 your app will Tell you in the stderr output after it has crashed where the recursion happened.

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 32128 times:
--------------------------------
   at SoExceptional.Program.RecursiveDeath()
--------------------------------
   at SoExceptional.Program.Main(System.String[])

Process finished with exit code -1,073,741,571.
```